# Calling an event when you press the enter button

Tags: javascript, html

There is a field to enter the name and password, as well as the login button. After entering the correct password and name, it is necessary that pressing the enter button triggers the login function, and if the entered password or name is incorrect, an input error message is displayed. An event click on enter should work regardless of the field in which the courses are located and regardless of whether the user has entered the data or not. It is necessary to implement using pure JS. Thank you in advance.

```
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" id="Name">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="password" id="Pass">
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Log In</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
function authorization(name, pass) {
  name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  pass = document.getElementById("Pass").value;

  if (name === "name") {
    if (pass === "pass") {
      document.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else {
      alert("Wrong password");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Wrong date")
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide us your JS code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use keypress/keyup event and check char code 13 for enter key.

Comment: Add a submit button. This is standard HTML functionality then, no need to write any javascript

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: "It is necessary to implement using pure JS" — You'll need DOM methods to acheive this. Pure JS has no means to interact with an HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button into a submit button, and bind a `submit` event listener to the form element.

Enter in an input in a form with only one submit button will trigger a submit event.

Comment: this is my js 
function authorization(name, pass) {
  name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  pass = document.getElementById("Pass").value;

  if (name === "name") {
    if (pass === "pass") {
      document.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else {
      alert("Wrong password");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Wrong date")
  }
}

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk — Well, it puts the username and password in the source code you are giving to the person trying to login, so it is useless … and it doesn't have a submit event listener in it, so it has nothing to do with what this answer tells you to do.

Comment: Submit Does not redirect to another page if the entered data is correct.

Comment: I know that this code is bad, so the question was formulated so that some kind person would help me write normal code =))

Answer (score -1):

change button type submit. inside from element button which type is submit is associated with submit event of the form.
and submit event works only when you are in focus in inputs fields
     Log In

Comment: you have to create submit event call for inputs

Comment: Submit Does not redirect to another page if the entered data is correct.

Answer (score -1):

This code helped me.

```
function login () {
      console.log('Вы нажали ENTER')
}

<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) login();" type="text" id="Name">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) login();" type="text" id="Pass">
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Log In</button>
</form>
```